# Is Google One-Tap Sign-Up available for browsers other than Chrome?

Tags: google-oauth, google-authentication, google-identity

The Google One-Tap Sign-Up documentation web page displays the following message:

> This API is currently in closed beta. We are improving the API's cross-browser functionality and will provide updates here in the coming months.

https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/

Is One-Tap Sign-Up safe for production use currently?

Also while testing the functionality I was not able to test this on non-Chrome browsers successfully. Is this available for browsers other than Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was also looking for a clear answer to this

from [troubleshooting page](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/troubleshooting):

> ...If you see the warning The client origin is not permitted to use this API, your service has not yet been accepted to the beta. New sign-ups to this beta are currently closed.

They also have a supported browser \ os table on there